# jQuery Loop Through dynamically Generated Checkboxes And Default Check Them All

Tags: jquery, loops

I have a variable that gets the select all checkboxes and associated ID with them in another function:

```
  var $allPdM = $('#SelectAll_' + pdmID);
```

In the $(document).ready(function() Currently, I have hard these hard coded in the page. However, I would like to do it dynamically now that I know there will be more coming:

```
  $('#SelectAll_2006').prop("checked",true);
  $('#SelectAll_2007').prop("checked",true);
  $('#SelectAll_2008').prop("checked",true);
```

This must be done on page load in the document.ready function.

Comment: Give them all a common class, then use `$(".class").prop("checked", true);`

Comment: How precisely would that look? I'm a back end Coldfusion Developer, I know little about jQuery.

Comment: It would look exactly like I showed. Just replace `class` with the actual class name, e.g. `$(".selectall")`

Comment: Isn't that what's there already with what I have hardcoded? There might be 5 instead of 3 so I would need to loop through wouldn't I?

Comment: There's nothing to loop through, there's just one class for all of them.

Comment: `<input id="SelectAll_2006" class="selectall" type="checkbox">`

Comment: Oh cool, so this then: $('#SelectAll_ + pdmID').prop("checked",true);

Comment: That didn't work. I did it wrong. Maybe this then- $(".SelectAll_" + pdmID).prop("checked",true);

Comment: I posted an answer several minutes ago.

Comment: ```$('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true)```

Comment: Also ```$('input[id^=SelectAll_]').prop('checked', true)```

Comment: jQuery works on collections, so if you did `$("input").prop("checked", true)` it would add the checked property to *all* inputs.  No need for an additional loop as jquery does that internally for you.   So by adding the *same* class to all of the inputs you want checked, you can select them *all* with a single class selector and add the property to all of them in a single call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give all the checkboxes a common class, and use that class when setting the property.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".selectall").prop("checked", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="2006" id="SelectAll_2006" class="selectall"> 2006<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="2007" id="SelectAll_2007" class="selectall"> 2007<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="2008" id="SelectAll_2008" class="selectall"> 2008<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="2009" id="SelectAll_2009" class="selectall"> 2009<br>
```

Comment: I need them all pre-selected when the page loads. No functions or clicking anything. How would I do that?

Comment: Something in the $(document).ready(function()

Comment: Yes, you can do that. This was just an example.

Comment: How? I'm not a jQuery expert.

Comment: I already updated the answer to show it

Comment: Ah I see. Added the class to the dynamically generated input device. Added the function to the Ready function and it works. Yay! Thanks.

Comment: If you want them "pre-selected when the page loads; no *functions*" then change the HTML.  `<input type='checkedbox' checked ...`